# am performing a login with django cutsom aunt but i get qoute_from_bytes() expected bytes error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

The Error!
`TypeError at /perform_login quote_from_bytes() expected bytes Request Method: POST Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/perform_login Django Version: 4.1.3 Exception Type: TypeError Exception Value:     quote_from_bytes() expected bytes Exception Location: C:\Users\DND\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\parse.py, line 895, in quote_from_bytes Raised during:  thena_users.views.perform_login Python Executable:  C:\Users\DND\PycharmProjects\thena\venv\Scripts\python.exe Python Version: 3.10.5 Python Path:     ['C:\\Users\\DND\\PycharmProjects\\thena\\thenadaka', 'C:\\Users\\DND\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\DND\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\DND\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\DND\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\DND\\PycharmProjects\\thena\\venv', 'C:\\Users\\DND\\PycharmProjects\\thena\\venv\\lib\\site-packages'] Server time:    Wed, 23 Nov 2022 08:25:33 +0000**your text**`

Perform_login is down here!

`

```
if request.method != 'POST':
    return HttpResponse('Method not allowed')
else:
    user_mail = request.POST.get('email field')
    password = request.POST.get('password field')
    if Users.objects.filter(email = user_mail, password= password).exists():
        user = Users.objects.get(email field = user_mail)
        request.session['user_id'] = #the user id field
        return redirect('templates/'where it redirects')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "username or password is incorrect")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request, '#templates for login')
```

`

I tried to login with wrong data so that i could be redirected to login page with an error message but instead got the error above

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a correct key value like this take white space in keys ...

```
user_mail = request.POST.get('email_field')
password = request.POST.get('password_field')
```